# How to change 'Aug 29, 2016' date format into dd/mm/yyyy either with formula or VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-formula

I've got a file with a date column which contains the dates in this format:

```
Aug 29, 2016
```

It's formatted as text, and changing the format of the column does not affect it. I need it in DD/MM/YYYY format. Previously, I was doing a formula along the lines of

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(AH2,5,2),"/08/2016")
```

But would have to change the "/08/2016" to whatever the month was. I'm looking for a more efficient way I can do this, preferably in a Macro, but a more dynamic formula would be helpful. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(AH2),"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

if the date format is not compatible with your system language setting, then you ought to put in additional functions. Below is tested for **English (Australia)**, further shorten from YowE3K suggestion..

```
=TEXT(--(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,2),",","")&LEFT(A1,3)&RIGHT(A1,4)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

sometimes the `TEXT()` is not really necessary because you can always use excel's more versatile number formatting. So you may just convert the dates into values (not as text) and apply the appropriate date format. The formula would be just

```
=--(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,2),",","")&LEFT(A1,3)&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

Comment: I'm using `English (Australia)` as my location and (although we would often write dates in the format the OP has) `DATEVALUE("Aug 29, 2016")` doesn't work for me.  It might be better to use `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,2)&" "&MID(A1,1,3)&MID(A1,8,5)),"dd/mm/yyyy")`.

Comment: Actually, it might be better to use `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,2),",","")&" "&LEFT(A1,3)&" "&RIGHT(A1,4)),"dd/mm/yyyy")` just in case the day is specified as a single digit.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @YowE3K's response, I was also using this long-winded solution:

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(AH2,5,2),"/",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Jan","01",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Feb","02",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Mar","03",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Apr","04",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "May","05",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Jun","06",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Jul","07",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Aug","08",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Sep","09",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Oct","10",IF(LEFT(AH2,3) = "Nov","11","12"),"/2016")
```

But YowE3K's is better!

Comment: another way instead of using many IF is `=CONCATENATE(MID(A1,5,2),"/",TEXT(MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0),"00"),"/",RIGHT(A1,4))`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers appear to be giving you the date format as text.  If this suits your needs, great.  However if you would prefer to have it in excels Date/Time format you can use to following.  I find that usually having the date and/or time in the excel format is better as you can then later use simpler formulas with it if there is any form of further manipulation that you may want to do with the dates such as a chronological sort instead of an alphabetical sort.

You are going to need to go through a series of string manipulation and date functions. Lets start by assuming your string is in the AH2 cell. In order to do this we are going to work from the largest unit (years) to the smallest unit (days). You can do it in any order as it will all be lumped into one formula in the end but for the breakdown of steps its good to have an order.

### Step 1) PULL OUT THE YEAR

```
=RIGHT(AH2,4)
```

That will give us the last 4 characters of the string which in this case is the year.

### Step 2) PULL OUT THE MONTH

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE(LEFT(AH2,3)&"-"&1))
```

that takes the first 3 characters which is your month. It then converts it to a format that excel tends to recognize as a date short form by adding a - and the digit 1 to it. So in your case if would look like Aug-1. Datevalue converts this to an excel date serial, which we then pull back and grab the month from and in your case that is 8

If the above formula does not work for you it could be due to regional settings. If that is the case you can use the following:

```
=MATCH(LEFT(AH2,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0)
```

If you use this alternate formula , be sure to adjust the final equation accordingly.

### Step 3) PULL OUT THE DAY

```
=TRIM(MID(AH2,FIND(",",AH2)-2,2))
```

The above formula finds the first comma, and then goes back 2 characters and then starts pulling then next 2 characters. Now since I do not know if the first of the month is 01 or just 1, it may wind up grabbing the space in front of the 1. The trim function removes excess spaces.

### Step 4) BUILD THE DATE

The DATE function in excel requires the YEAR, MONTH, and DAY and converts those values in to the excel date serial. In this case we will convert:

```
=DATE(year,month,day)
```

to the following by substituting our equations from above:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(AH2,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(LEFT(AH2,3)&"-"&1)),TRIM(MID(AH2,FIND(",",AH2)-2,2)))
```

The final touch is to ensure your cell is formatted as date and not General or some other format which will result as the date being displayed in an integer format.

### FORMULAS USED

Text/String Functions

- [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)
- [RIGHT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f)
- [MID](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MID-MIDB-functions-D5F9E25C-D7D6-472E-B568-4ECB12433028)
- [FIND](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-C7912941-AF2A-4BDF-A553-D0D89B0A0628)
- [TRIM](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9)

Date/Time Functions

- [DATE](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/DATE-function-E36C0C8C-4104-49DA-AB83-82328B832349)
- [DATEVALUE](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252)
- [MONTH](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8)